# Int to String type conversion

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion

I am a beginner to Python .Below is the code which i tried yesterday

```
x=52
y =43
str(x)
str(y)
print(x + y)
```

The outcome was 95 & not 5243 . I wanted to know thatif I converted those variable into string then why it is adding them mathematically ?

Comment: you should assing the variable after casting, i.e. `x = str(x)`

Answer (score 2):

what you have done is, you are not re-assigning the casted value to x and y. Refer the code below:

```
x=52
y =43
x=str(x)  # converting x from integer to string and then re-assigning x
y=str(y)  # converting y from integer to string and then re-assigning y
print(x + y)
```